# Regular expression for highlighting words

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find all positions of a word within a string.

This version nearly works, but it doesn't find the first and the last occurence:

```
while ('abc abc abc abc' =~ /(?<=\W)abc(?=\W)/g)
{
    print $-[0] . ' - ' . $+[0] . "\n";
}
```

This version finds all occurences, but prints the warning *Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex*.

```
while ('abc abc abc abc' =~ /(?<=\W|^)abc(?=\W|$)/g)
{
    print $-[0] . ' - ' . $+[0] . "\n";
}
```

I understand the reason for the warning, but what could be a better solution?

Comment: I think you mean the opposite of the lookarounds `(?<!\w)abc(?!\w)` https://regex101.com/r/lwXvtS/1

Comment: Use `\b` to assert word boundaries, i.e. `\babc\b`

Comment: The first comment solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that hyphenated words, and words with apostrophes will fail to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the query is indeed to walk over matches

```
say "$+[0] - $-[0]" while $string =~ /abc/g;
```

and then the remaining issue is to specify the pattern to match what is (actually) needed. But I don't see that a blanket lookaround would be a general, or best, solution to that.

If a "word" need be matched as hinted then a *word boundary* anchor (`\b`) is suitable

```
perl -wE'$_=q(ah aha ah no ah); say "$-[0] - $+[0]" while /\bah\b/g;'
```

The exact pattern to use depends on the exact requirements of course, but now the job is down to writing a suitable pattern, and that is good.
 Once you identify *exactly* what is a valid word in your use then a 
character class can be a practical solution, if your word is more than the regex's "word".<sup>†</sup>

The above one-liner prints

```
0 - 2
7 - 9
13 - 15
```

**Note**   For `say` [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) used above you need `use feature qw(say);` at the top, or `use v5.10;` (or higher), or to `use` a module that enables it (and many large frameworks do.

---

<sup>†</sup> The regex "word" is a bit restrictive, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and so unsuitable for some common needs.

For example, if a hyphen and an apostrophe may be found in your words as well then `[\w\-']+` would take care of that. If for some reason a pattern like that can't be used for the word itself (an alternation of a set of specific key words?) then it can work for a negative look-around.

An example, seeking words (`ab`, `c-d`, `e'f`) in a given string

```
my $word = join '|', map { quotemeta } qw(ab c-d e'f);  #' alternation of words
my $wc = qr/[\w\-']/;                                   #' word-characters

my $string = q(ab and a c-d and an e'f, but no c-d's);  #'

say $1 while $string =~ /(?<!$wc)($word)(?!$wc)/g
```

(This discusses the regex alone but it works for the position-quest of the question.)

This code, made-up in the absence of specifics, may need tweaking for any particular use.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
while ('abc abc abc abc' =~ /(?:^|(?<=\W))abc(?=$|\W)/g) {
    say "$-[0] - $+[0]";
}
```

But there are simpler solutions. Instead of looking for `\W`, look for the absence of a `\w`.

```
while ('abc abc abc abc' =~ /(?<!\w)abc(?!\w)/g) {
    say "$-[0] - $+[0]";
}
```

It's even simpler to use `\b`.

```
while ('abc abc abc abc' =~ /\babc\b/g) {
    say "$-[0] - $+[0]";
}
```

This last solution assumes that `abc` is a placeholder for something that starts with a `\w` char and ends with a `\w` char.